# Does ui:insert support only html fragments or also complete html pages

Tags: jsf-2

I have been told (on stack overflow) that the JSF 2.0 `ui:insert` directive is for html *fragments* only - not for complete html pages.

Can anyone point me to the JSF spec that confirms this?

Comment: Do you mean `ui:import` or `ui:include`/`ui:insert`?

Comment: You can get the JSF 2.0 specs from [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/)

Comment: Mubin asked that because the `<ui:import>` doesn't exist at all. Perhaps you were confusing with `<c:import>`?

Comment: Thanks for the information. This has been updated.

Comment: Thanks @Mubin - I'm looking at the specs at the following location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jsf-2_0-fr-spec.pdf - I see only one reference to ui:include and it doesn't answer my question. Could you help me out?

Comment: With `ui:include` you can refer to a complete html pages as well. The restriction that you are talking about is for `ui:insert`. Check this javadoc [here](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/)